# GET REAL TIME CURRENCY EXCHANGE RATE

Tags: equities, programming, fx, price, exchange

I need to get currency exchange rates in real time, every seconds.

On websites or when using APIs, the rates are only updated every minutes, or every 30s...

Is there any way I can get these datas, updated every seconds ? Any website or API ?

Thank you

Comment: This data is hard to get, check the linked topic for online data sources.

Comment: If you really need this every second, you will need reliable sources (Reuters, Bloomberg as the standard go to providers). However, they charge for extra data licenses if you need this for applications. For example, a normal Bloomberg terminal license would not allow you to feed their data into anything.